# NoSuchMethodError: org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log while deploying application on a WebSphere 7.0.0.23 Application Server

Tags: 2011, java

I am facing the error below while deploying an application onto a WebSphere 7.0.0.23 Application Server:

> [10/25/13 12:07:34:813 IST] 00000035 StorageManage E
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory reloadInstance Fatal error,
>   unable to load the StorageManagerFactory java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:456)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:394)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:25)
>   at
>   com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:139)
>   at com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:107) at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:106)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:86)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:58)
>   at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200) at
>   com.tridion.broker.querying.Query.(Query.java:45) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.impl.TridionDynamicWrapper.getSystemConfigDetails(TridionDynamicWrapper.java:650)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.impl.TridionDynamicWrapper.getWSConfigBySchema(TridionDynamicWrapper.java:522)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.processor.TridionDynamicProcessor.getData(TridionDynamicProcessor.java:68)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.processor.GenericDataProcessor.getData(GenericDataProcessor.java:38)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.service.DataLayerService.getData(DataLayerService.java:296)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.getConfiguration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:438)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.initializeConfigurationInformation(ConfigServiceImpl.java:226)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.initConfiguration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:153)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.init(ConfigServiceImpl.java:64)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.startService(ServiceHandler.java:96)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.startAllNewServices(ServiceHandler.java:74)
>   at com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.init(ServiceHandler.java:57)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.FrameworkLoader.startAllServices(FrameworkLoader.java:346)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.FrameworkLoader.init(FrameworkLoader.java:106)
>   at com.aig.ebiz.framework.Framework.init(Framework.java:128) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.Framework.createContext(Framework.java:96) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.listeners.ApplicationContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationContextListener.java:23)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1708)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:381)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1127)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1272)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5353)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5441)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1277)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:599)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:561)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1184)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256) at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1407)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1303)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1263)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256) at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:453)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:286)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
>   at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532) at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
>
> [10/25/13 12:07:35:470 IST] 00000035 FfdcProvider  W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident
>   emitted on C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_53a353a3_13.10.25_12.07.34.9703640951413521736223.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
>   [10/25/13 12:07:35:470 IST] 00000035 webappE
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated
>   SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0} 
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222) at
>   com.tridion.broker.querying.Query.(Query.java:45) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.impl.TridionDynamicWrapper.getSystemConfigDetails(TridionDynamicWrapper.java:650)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.impl.TridionDynamicWrapper.getWSConfigBySchema(TridionDynamicWrapper.java:522)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.processor.TridionDynamicProcessor.getData(TridionDynamicProcessor.java:68)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.processor.GenericDataProcessor.getData(GenericDataProcessor.java:38)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.integration.service.DataLayerService.getData(DataLayerService.java:296)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.getConfiguration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:438)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.initializeConfigurationInformation(ConfigServiceImpl.java:226)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.initConfiguration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:153)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.ebp.config.impl.ConfigServiceImpl.init(ConfigServiceImpl.java:64)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.startService(ServiceHandler.java:96)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.startAllNewServices(ServiceHandler.java:74)
>   at com.aig.ebiz.framework.ServiceHandler.init(ServiceHandler.java:57)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.FrameworkLoader.startAllServices(FrameworkLoader.java:346)
>   at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.FrameworkLoader.init(FrameworkLoader.java:106)
>   at com.aig.ebiz.framework.Framework.init(Framework.java:128) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.Framework.createContext(Framework.java:96) at
>   com.aig.ebiz.framework.listeners.ApplicationContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationContextListener.java:23)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1708)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:381)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1127)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1272)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5353)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5441)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1277)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:599)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:561)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1184)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256) at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1407)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1303)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1263)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256) at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:453)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:286)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
>   at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532) at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the
>   StorageManagerFactory at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:93)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:58)
>   at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200) ... 92 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:456)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:394)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:25)
>   at
>   com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:139)
>   at com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:107) at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:106)
>   at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:86)
>   ... 95 more

**UPDATE:**
I have installed RAD8.0 With WAS 7.0.023. After that I have imported EAR file in to my local workspace, then I build the workspace then deployed on WASserver. so I am getting this on while publishing the application. But the same code is working on other's environment

Comment: Can you share your code sample

Comment: @Chaitanya can you edit your question and provide more information to what you are actually trying to achieve and what you have done? From the error message we gather you are trying to deploy a web application which uses the SDL Tridion Content Delivery API, but you don't specify if you have actually followed the documentation and have deployed the correct JARs and configuration files. With this little information, this question is not going to get an answer as nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry Pankaj, as per company policy I am unable to share code.. but I will explain the problem I have newly joined into this project, I have installed RAD8.0 With WAS 7.0.023. After that I have imported EAR file in to my local workspace, then I build the workspace then deployed on was server. so I am getting this on while publishing the application. but same code is working on other's environment.  Request you to help.

Comment: 1) I am trying to build a new development workspace in my local system. 2) I have installed RAD 8.0 With WAS 7.0.26 3) I am using jre1.6 version 4) also we are using Tridion 2011 version. 5) I have taken a running EAR file from team mate 6) The same EAR file imported in to my local RAD workspace 7) then I have build and deployed on WAS server 8) I am getting the above posted error while staring/publicing application into WAR server.                                              Note: Please let me know if you require any information.

Comment: @Chaitanya please use the EDIT button on your question and add your information in the question instead of using the comments, this is not clear nor readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are saying that the same code is working on some other computer but not yours, can you ensure it has been compiled correctly?

May be you can try compiling from the Command Line instead of Eclipse.

Also, if you are still compiling from the Eclipse, then ensure `Add directory` entries option is checked on the first screen of the export wizard.

May be you want to follow [THIS](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/storage-extension-for-dynamic-component-presentations/) post - specifically the Caution section and see if you have followed all of them correctly.

I have seen this problem quite a number of time and because of the ill-compiled JAR files and in specific the below two lines did not get compiled properly:

```
@Component(“<your-storage-extension-class-name>”)
@Scope(“prototype”)
```

You may want to check if some additional settings need to be done in your editor to properly compile and export your code.

**UPDATE:**
Not sure if you updated your question, but earlier when I read your question, I guess it was for the Storage Extension..isn't it?

Comment: I have tried another way .. I have directly deployed running EAR file on WAS server using( https://localhost:9043/ibm/console) here I'm not using any IDE like RAD or eclips software. still I am facing same error/issue, any idea!! Thanks inadvance.

Comment: In addition to what Raimond has recommended in his answer, did you verify that all the JAR files which are available on the Running instance are available on your WAS server.
Also verify if there is some reference to third party JARs/WARs in your code which might be available on the running instance but not on the WAS server

Answer (score 3):

From the stacktrace it seems that you are missing the logging jar file. Ensure that slf4j-api.jar is found on the classpath. Be sure to package the ear with not only the Tridion config files, but also with this minimum set of jar files you can find on your installation media.

Comment: Yes I have configured required 1.6 version jar files like jcl-over-slf4j.jar, slf4j-api.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar files under WEB-INF/lib folder also same jar file updated at WAS runtime environment Optional library section (C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\web2fep\optionalLibraries & C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\web2mobilefep_1.1)

Comment: @Chaitanya please ensure that the jars used are the ones coming from the SDL Tridion installation folder/media, as there are several versions of these jars available and SDL Tridion will require the one it has delivered to you specifically. If your web application also makes use of these common libraries, always make sure you choose the one delivered with SDL Tridion over your own, else version conflicts can occur.

Comment: It's not necessarily that he's missing a JAR (or he would get a ClassNotFoundException), but likely he has a different version of the JAR, with the same class in it, but with different method overloads.

Comment: Agreed. This might be caused by WAS loading a shared older (< 1.5) version of the slf4j / log4j api.

Answer (score 2):

A `NoSuchMethodError` exception indicates you have a different JAR versions between your compilation environment and your runtime environment.

So you compiled your code with a JAR version that contains class `LocationAwareLogger` with method `log(Marker, String, String, Object, Throwable)`.

Now at runtime (on WAS), you are missing that JAR and instead you have different version of that JAR containing another version of class `LocationAwareLogger` that does not contain that particular `log` method.

The fix would be to copy the JARs you compiled your code with to the runtime WAS server.